# A simple console calculator

Tags: java

I have designed a simple console calculator as follows but i need to create a loop where I can re run the program:

So that I won't need to run the program again and again and it can take the input from the user and run by itself.

```
private static Scanner op;
private static Scanner input;
private static Scanner cont;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double ans = 0;
    double l1;
    double l2;
    String operation;

    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your first number:");
    num1= input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please input the second numer:");
    num2= input.nextDouble();

    op = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select your operation:");
    operation = op.next();

    if (operation.equals("+")){
        System.out.println("Your Result is :" + (num1+num2));
    }
    if (operation.equals("-")){
        System.out.println("Your Result is:" + (num1-num2));
    }
    if (operation.equals("/")){
        if (num2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Your Input is Invalid");}
            else {
                System.out.println("Your result is :" + (num1/num2));
            }

        }
        if (operation.equals("*")){
            System.out.println("Your result is:" + (num1*num2));
        }
        if (operation.equals("%")){
           System.out.println("Your result is:" + (num1*100/num2));
        }
        if (operation.equals("^")){
            ans= Math.pow(num1, num2);
            System.out.println("Your result is:"+ans);
        }
        if (operation.equals("log")){
            l1=Math.log(num1);
            l2=Math.log(num2);
           System.out.println("Your result is:"+l1/l2);
        }
        operation = cont.next();
        System.out.println("Do you wish to perform any other operation?");
        if (operation.equals("Yes")){

        else{
            System.out.println("Thank You");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, do you know how to write a while loop?

Comment: just call `main` again.

Comment: while loops: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function and call it with a loop like this:

```
private static void myfunction(){
    //put your code here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //call your function until your condition is false
    while(myconditionistrue){
        myfunction();
    }
}
```

if you want to ask your user if continue or not use this way:

```
private static void myfunction() {
    //put your code here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String exit;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        //call your function or you can put all your code here
        myfunction();
        System.out.println("You want to continue? y : n :");
        exit = scan.next();
    } while (exit.equals("y"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while(true)` and then just exit at command:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Main {
    private static Scanner op;
    private static Scanner input;
    private static Scanner cont;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double num1;
        double num2;
        double ans = 0;
        double l1;
        double l2;
        String operation;
        while (true) {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input your first number:");
            num1 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please input the second numer:");
            num2 = input.nextDouble();

            op = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Select your operation:");
            operation = op.next();

            if (operation.equals("+")) {
                System.out.println("Your Result is :" + (num1 + num2));
            }
            if (operation.equals("-")) {
                System.out.println("Your Result is:" + (num1 - num2));
            }
            if (operation.equals("/")) {
                if (num2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your Input is Invalid");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your result is :" + (num1 / num2));
                }
                ;

            }
            if (operation.equals("*")) {
                System.out.println("Your result is:" + (num1 * num2));
            }
            if (operation.equals("%")) {
                System.out.println("Your result is:" + (num1 * 100 / num2));
            }
            if (operation.equals("^")) {
                ans = Math.pow(num1, num2);
                System.out.println("Your result is:" + ans);
            }
            if (operation.equals("log")) {
                l1 = Math.log(num1);
                l2 = Math.log(num2);
                System.out.println("Your result is:" + l1 / l2);
            }
            //cont = new Scanner(System.in);

            //operation = cont.next();
            System.out.println("Do you wish to perform any other operation?");

            cont = new Scanner(System.in);

            operation = cont.next();


            if (operation.equals("Yes")) {

            } else {
                System.out.println("Thank You");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
Please input your first number:
5
Please input the second numer:
5
Select your operation:
*
Your result is:25.0
Do you wish to perform any other operation?
Yes
Please input your first number:
20
Please input the second numer:
10
Select your operation:
+
Your Result is :30.0
Do you wish to perform any other operation?
No
Thank You
```

Answer (score 0):

As RealSkeptic stated in his comment, what you need is a loop. You can learn about loops, for example, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm). The best choice for this situation is **do-while loop**.

---

I have a few more advices to your code:

- You don't need to create many scanners to get more inputs than just one. One instance suffices.
- When you use many *if* statements whose conditions are disjoint (by that I mean that if a single condition is true then the rest of the conditions is false), use *else-if* statements. It is more efficient. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) for more information.
- Don't use empty branches in *if* statement. In this particular example, you can use `if (!operation.equals("Yes"))`. The exclamation mark means negation. So if `operation` equals "Yes", the whole condition is evaluated as false.
- Learn how to divide a complex code into functions (or methods). Generally, one function should provide one simple functionality.